# while read line in awk and using $line

Tags: awk, while-loop, readline

this is my file

air1.txt

```
fc:75:16:d2:91:a3   -90 targol
78:54:2e:7f:e8:9e   -88 DLink
fc:75:16:d2:91:a3   -89 targol
78:54:2e:7f:e8:9e   -89 DLink
78:54:2e:7f:e8:9e   -88 DLink
78:54:2e:7f:e8:9e   -87 DLink
fc:75:16:d2:91:a3   -90 targol
```

I want to calculate the average of second column for each name in the third column! Here is my scrip!

```
RSSI=$(awk '{print $3}' air1.txt | sort -u | while read line; do awk < air1.txt '{print $2,$3}' | grep $line | ./rssiMean.sh |cut -d'.' -f1 |awk '{print $line,$1}' ;done)
echo $RSSI
```

but the result is

```
-88 -88 -89 -89
```

Why I can't get `$line`?!
BTW ./rssiMean.sh calculate the average!

Comment: This `awk < air1.txt '{print $2,$3}'` is something I have not seen before.  What are your trying to do here. Its normal `awk 'code' file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use bash variables as such in `awk` script.

Rather use a awk variable and assign the value using the `-v` paramter

eg:

```
$var=123
$awk -v awkvar=$var '{print awkvar}'
```

here `awkvar` is an awk varible created and passed with value of `$var`

to make this change in your script

```
RSSI=$(awk '{print $3}' air1.txt | sort -u | while read line; do awk < air1.txt '{print $2,$3}' | grep $line | ./rssiMean.sh |cut -d'.' -f1  |awk -v line=$line '{print line,$1}' ;done)
echo $RSSI
```

The change made is

`awk -v line=$line '{print line,$1}`

awk varible `line` is assigned with value of bash varibale `$line`

Comment: But if yo want to take the average of the column I would suggest  Jotne's answer

Answer (score 3):

This should do:

```
awk '{a[$3]+=$2;b[$3]++} END {for (i in a) print i,a[i]/b[i]}' air1.txt
DLink -88
targol -89.6667
```

It sum up number for every data in column #3 and divide it by number of hits.

Comment: what should I do if also want to sort the data according to the third column?

Comment: @sgh Just pipe it to `sort` and it will sort based on route type: `awk '{a[$3]+=$2;b[$3]++} END {for (i in a) print i,a[i]/b[i]}' air1.txt | sort`